# clojure.spec validation for fdef

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am trying to write a higher order function in [clojure.spec](http://clojure.org/guides/spec) with version `1.9.0-alpha11` and have not been able to get the validation to execute against the returned function.

Using the example in the **Higher order functions** section of the clojure.spec guide, I define an `adder` form as:

```
(defn adder [x] #(+ x %))
```

As described in the guide, I create a spec as:

```
(s/fdef adder
  :args (s/cat :x number?)
  :ret (s/fspec :args (s/cat :y number?)
                :ret number?)
  :fn #(= (-> % :args :x) ((:ret %) 0)))
```

When I execute it in the repl, an exception is thrown instead of the desired spec validation error:

```
user> (def add2 (adder 2))
#'user/add2
user> (add2 2)
4
user> (add2 "s")
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.add (Numbers.java:128)                                                                                                                                                           
user>
```

I attempted to turn spec'ing on with `` (stest/instrument `adder) ``. While this works for functions, it is not working for **Higher order functions**.

Comment: I could reproduce the same behavior. Where exactly refers your last "as described above" to? And is the double backtick a typo or intended?

Comment: @AntonHarald. I updated the code block. The "as described above" refers to the bolded **Higher Order Functions** at the top of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands in clojure 1.9-alpha14 higher order functions cannot be validated in that way. Looking at `clojure.spec.test/instrument`, it is looking for functions in spec's registry, which will only include fdef'd functions.

The fspec in the `:ret` will be used when testing `adder` via `clojure.spec.test/check` and alongside documenting the function that is the value of it.